# SQL insert query so slow

Tags: mysql, sql

Each 10,000 rows take about 124 second to insert ,how this can be faster

This is the table i insert to

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` 
(`oid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`countryCode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`date` datetime NOT NULL,
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`productId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`oid`),
UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
KEY `date` (`date`),
KEY `productId` (`productId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4833010 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

this is the query i used

```
ALTER TABLE `orders` DISABLE KEYS;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
INSERT IGNORE INTO `orders` (`countryCode`, `date`, `id`,`productId`) 
VALUES 
    ('ru','2019-04-09 06:59',100453324298986,32829863707) ,
    ('fr','2019-04-09 05:59',100645420835625,32829863707) ,
    ('ru','2019-04-08 12:04',704482263524094,32829863707) 
    .......etc 10,000 rows here at once
```

Comment: . . I would recommend storing the data in a file and using `load data infile`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Good idea, but that wouldn't have the same behavior as `INSERT IGNORE`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen There's an `IGNORE` option in `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

Comment: @Barmar You should post this as an answer then :-)

Comment: Are the client and server on the same machine? If they're connected over a network, that will probably be the bottleneck.

Comment: i noticed that my hdd is at 100% use once the inserting start,im running on testing machine no other users.

Comment: What client are you using?

Comment: MySQL,and testing the insert in phpmyadmin also using php ,im reading files from the disk and converting them to sql queries then inserting them

Answer (score 0):

Try to write insert statement as

```
START TRANSACTION;  
INSERT INTO `insert_table` (`datetime`, `uid`, `content`, `type`) VALUES ('0', 'userid_0', 'content_0', 0);  
INSERT INTO `insert_table` (`datetime`, `uid`, `content`, `type`) VALUES ('1', 'userid_1', 'content_1', 1);  
...  
COMMIT;
```

Comment: is this going to ignore the duplicate and you are using a single insert line for each insert !?

Comment: Doing lots of single-row inserts is almost always slower than doing them in bulk. It has to parse each query from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's slow because you trying to INSERT bulk records at once.
You have several methods to speedup the process.

1) Insert records batch wise. ( 500-1000 records at a time )

2) Increase Memory parameters in MYSQL. so the memory will be increased.
(http://www.geeksengine.com/database/data-manipulation/bulk-insert.php)

**Try This for batch Update**

```
SET autocommit=0;
SET unique_checks=0;
SET foreign_key_checks=0;
SET GLOBAL bulk_insert_buffer_size =1024*1024*512;

START TRANSACTION;  

INSERT IGNORE INTO `orders` (`countryCode`, `date`, `id`,`productId`) 
VALUES 
    ('ru','2019-04-09 06:59',100453324298986,32829863707) ,
    ('fr','2019-04-09 05:59',100645420835625,32829863707) ,
    ('ru','2019-04-08 12:04',704482263524094,32829863707) 
    .......etc 600 rows here at once

COMMIT;

START TRANSACTION;  

INSERT IGNORE INTO `orders` (`countryCode`, `date`, `id`,`productId`) 
VALUES 
    ('ru','2019-04-09 06:59',100453324298986,32829863707) ,
    ('fr','2019-04-09 05:59',100645420835625,32829863707) ,
    ('ru','2019-04-08 12:04',704482263524094,32829863707) 
    .......etc 600 rows here at once

COMMIT;
```

**Note:**

1) If this is slow Try changing bulk_insert_buffer_size  and no of rows per insert.

2) Check your PC Free Memory/CPU  before executing the query . try to free it as much as possible

Comment: ok let me know.i think best thing is batch insert. You can set AutoCommit off and start a transaction and for every 1000 records commit the transaction.
It will speedup the process.

Comment: This is worse i sectioned the query into 600 rows at each insert ,but it took more time.

Comment: Hi i updated the solution . please check it.
Sources : 

1) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-optimization.html
2) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html

If this is not working try increasing the Mysql cache , heap , buffer memory variables. 

Once i speed up the process 100x times faster with increasing the memories and database indexing.

Comment: You can check the sources i attached in previous comment. it is from official site.

Comment: Okey i will test this but "SET unique_checks=0;" is this going to allow inserting of duplicated values or  not ?

Comment: yes.but if you want to check unique. please comment it and execute.